# String comparison functions are not working properly

Tags: vba

So I have a program that I have three groups of users, and I am storing user names, permission levels, usernames and passwords in a veryhidden/protected sheet. (Yes I know this is not particularly secure but it is not to prevent malintent it simply will avoid people stumbling upon things they shouldnt. Nobody is going to be able to uncover very hidden sheets or get into the code.)
The function below is what I have been using. The for each loop is going into the users sheet and finding the username, but for some reason it says that the password is wrong no matter what. I do not know a ton about string comparison and I suspect that one of my conversions or the way I am comparing the passwords is not doing it's job. I have tweaked this a bunch of different ways, but I am missing something basic I think.

```
Function getSecurityLevel(user As String, pw As String) As Single
Dim userNames As Range
Dim thisUser As Range
Dim uName
Dim userWS As Worksheet
 Set userWS = Worksheets("Users")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Module4.unprotectUsers
 Set userNames = userWS.ListObjects("userTable").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

For Each thisUser In userNames
 If LCase(CStr(thisUser.Text)) = LCase(user) Then
  uName = thisUser.Address
 Range(uName).Offset(0, 1).Select
 If CStr(ActiveCell.Text) <> pw Then
   MsgBox "Your password is incorrect", vbOKOnly
   Exit For
  Else
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
 getSecurityLevel = ActiveCell.Value
 Exit For
 End If
 End If
Next thisUser
Module4.hideAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Your username could not be found, please try again", vbOKOnly
End Function
```

I just need it to properly compare the input password from the userform to the cell next to the matching username, then offset one more and read the security level

Comment: As an input from the userform when I call this it is just LCase(Me.userName.Text) and Me.pw.Text

Comment: Setting the concern I mentioned earlier aside and actually evaluating your code, I assume `userWS` is your "hidden" worksheet.  If so, then it is very likely your use of `*.Select` and `ActiveCell` that's causing the problem. Should be easily tested with `Debug.Print Selection.Parent.Name = userWS.Name`. I suspect the result will be`False` but your code indicates you expect it to be `True`. There are a few reasons to use `Select` but this is not one of them.  Explicitly set the value to a variable and make your comparison that way.  Let me know if that helps.  I will revisit if needed.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, i dropped the use of active cell and set the row value equal to a variable to solve the problem and pull the values I wanted. I am still storing in the sheet but I am using an xor encryption function with their password as the key that encrypts their other info into usernames and passwords that are unreadable so its a bit more secure. I am getting a type mismatch I have been struggling with, do you mind if I message you?

Comment: Nope, I don't mind at all.  Send it on over.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer you want but you need to know this.

"Nobody is going to be able to uncover very hidden sheets or get into the code."  That is a bold statement and also very untrue.

Setting aside the fact that password protection offered by the VB editor is easily broken.

Anyone with access to the file can change the extension to ZIP.  From there, everyone's password is visible as plain text in `xl\sharedstrings.xml` and your vaunted very hidden worksheet is plainly visible in the file structure and can be unhidden by removing `state="veryHidden"` in `xl\workbook.xml` then rezipping and replacing ZIP with the appropriate Excel extension.

Do your users a favor. If you're not going to encrypt passwords and insist on storing them as plain text - then at the very least, do not save them in a file that is distributed to all of your users.

What happens if that file is sent to someone outside the organization or if anyone in your company caught whiff of you sending unencrypted passwords to your users...  Think man!  This is not the way forward!!!

Comment: Its just being used by electricians and its not blocking things that are confidential, rather just keeping them out of the way to avoid confusion. This is not a finance program or anything. I can save them in a text file though youre probably right, I also will need to store security levels and such and I just have not figured out how to do that, but I will take the time. If you have any resources that are particularly helpful on this please let me know

Comment: I use security as a loose term just to refer to what portions of it are relevant to whom, overall this does not need anything special in terms of actual security

Comment: in fact, a bunch of the users are running off ipads, and those users will have no security because they cant run macros, and the sheet is fully locked on default. since that group cannot input credentials, they just see the most basic form of the sheet. Theoretically yes they could access code and find the other sheets but as I mentioned it is not confidential. I would like to explore a better way to do that but have not been able to figure out the other methods

Comment: Each copy of the program will  only be used by primarily two people, then there will be people with admin credentials. All that I need to do is determine if the person is a project manager, if so if they belong to the project that the book is for, or if they are an admin. If they are one of those, unlock relevant sheets. If not, then it remains at default which is all sheets locked but two. If you open from an ipad then all sheets remain locked as well as you cannot run code to unlock the others. I would love advice on how to handle this!